# Adding other GA properties into an existing GTM container

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm fairly new to GTM. I've inherited a GTM account with an existing container for our corporate website with existing tags etc. I've been asked to add some microsites to this container, keeping their own GA ID properties.

I've read that the best way to handle the different GA properties is to use a lookup table to set the Tracking ID in the GA settings tag, so the GA tracking tags would use the same GA setup tag but the Tracking ID would vary according to the hostname.

Do I create one lookup table for all the microsites?
Do I need to create a Google Analytics Universal tag for each GA property?
How do these link with the lookup table.
If someone could break this down into steps I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using GA UA tags may be unwise since it will be discontinued in about a year. I would suggest going GA4 with all new implementations right away unless otherwise explicitly requested.
2. You make one lookup table, may as well make it regex lookup table if you're good at regex and if regex is needed. May as well use a custom javascript variable rather than the raw page hostname if you don't mind JS. Both JS and regex will just add a lot more flexibility while still keeping your work well structured.
3. In it, map your hostnames to GA tracking ids.
4. Starting from here, the implementation will differ between UA and GA4, but I will stick to GA4. Make a pageview tag like so: [image]
5. Use that pageview as a config for all subsequent GA4 events that should fire along the same logic outlined in the LUT (Look Up Table)

Comment: Thanks @BNararuk - I will see how I go and hopefully get it working.

Comment: Hi @BNazaruk. Do I need to set a trigger as well?

Comment: no, no need to add a trigger if your main trigger triggers on the microsites too. The variable should solve it for all sites, just don't forget to make sure that it routes the main site correctly. Well, you may choose to decouple the microsites and the main site logic. Then you'd need a new trigger and a new tag. Up to you.

Comment: I'm a bit stuck. It's not a new implementation, so I've used the GA UA tag and hence had to create a variable. Now I have this variable along with the look up table variable. In Preview I'm not seeing anything firing, it says Legacy tag detected? Is there another part to this I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: ok, well, that looks to me like a different question and different debugging now. Legacy tag may imply something odd, so I would suggest sharing a screenshot of it as well as the rest of your debugging attempts in a new question.